# Cannot script Extended Event in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I want to script an extended event session out in SSMS and I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

I also get the error when I try to script it in PowerShell.  Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.  When I created the extended event I accidentally added the sqlserver.session_id field twice to the output.  The event still worked but would not script out.